# Is this in possible to do in graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[image]

the conditions are that 
vetex if G lies in the same connected components of G and every vertex has the same degree. 
The left hand side all have degree three except for two, so is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You don't need every vertex to have the same degree, you just need them all to have $\textit{even}$ degree. Note that the only vertices with odd degree are $a$, $e$, $l$, and $k$. Now you just need to add edges to connect the graph and make sure every vertex has even degree.